# Change pivot position without moving the drawing

Tags: c#, math, pivot

I want to change the pivot "safely". When changing the pivot, I want the drawing rectangle to stay at the same position, but make the pivot (and XY position with it) change.

Here's the image of what I mean:
[image: Pivot change without moving green box]

My pivots work like: `PivotX=0 PivotY=0` is top left corner, `PivotX=1 PivotY=1` is bottom right corner of the rectangle.

Now here's my problem, the code:

```
public void ChangePivot(float pivotX, float pivotY)
{
    float oldPivotX = PivotX; // PivotX is object's variable
    float oldPivotY = PivotY; // PivotY is object's variable
    PivotX = pivotX;
    PivotY = pivotY;
    X -= (oldPivotX - PivotX) * Width * (float)Math.Cos(Rotation * Math.PI / 180);  // X and Rotation are object's variables
    Y -= (oldPivotY - PivotY) * Height * (float)Math.Cos(Rotation * Math.PI / 180);  // Y and Rotation are object's variables
}
```

Pivot change works perfectly on X axis, but doesn't on Y axis.

**Edit: I found the problem at the Cos part**

I'm overall looking for "safe change pivot" formula. I couldn't find one, probably as I can't describe this thing in few keywords. So this is kind of my best own solution.

Thanks for any help!

Apollogies for being a math noob. :D

Comment: Why are you multiplying by Cos when you are not rotating the drawing?

Comment: Because I need to rotate the drawing sometimes. Forgot to tell

Comment: The formula doesn't make a lot of sense for both x and y.  Why are you multiplying by the different between old and new value?

Comment: Because I need to push the rectangle by the difference between these two points. The width/height here is just kind of "convertor" that converts pivot difference to XY units. Note the `-=`. The code **works on 0 and 180 degree rotation**, so I assume the problem only in the Cos part.

Comment: To move X or Y you should not be multiplying by Height and Width.  Doesn't make any sense.  You are not "scaling" the size of the rectangles.  Just moving left, right up, and down.

Comment: It probably makes sense when it works like it should on 0 angle. I think you didn't get what I mean which is alright because I really don't know how to explain the code in the detail, as my engine has kinda connected everything with everything. I'll say it differently. Pivot in my program is a **percentage position** between _top left corner XY position_ of the drawing, and _Width and Height_. Multiplying the pivot difference by Width/Height can compute the **unit** difference. If you think about it more, you'll see it, just try. We're talking about thing that works correctly anyways.

Comment: A percentage of WHAT???  If you are doing a percentage then you shouldn't be subtracting (old - new).  It would be more like [new * (width - old)].

Comment: Tried your way, didn't work. Rectange got pushed to the left always. My way works, look at this, tried my real best to explain: [image](http://i.imgur.com/Lhz60eQ.png)

Comment: Your image give inconsistent results and only works if you are at 0,0.  the possible range of values for X or Y can be from -1 to +1   Lets assume you are at 0.5,0.5.  A value of -1 will give a results of -1 * Width while +1 will give a value of 1.5 * Width.  What make the most sense is the amount of movement is a percentage of the Width (or Height).  So the formula is X += (PivotX * Width) where PivotX is from -1 to + 1.

Comment: I don't know, I didn't have any problems with pivot in range 0.0 to 1.0. Is that a reason why the rotation doesn't give proper results?

Comment: Rotation of 0=1, 90=0, 180=-1, 270=0.

Comment: Alright thanks I'll give it some tryings

Comment: Your solution kind of works as well, but I'm still having problems at the rotations different than 0 and 180.

Comment: Rotation in this case only changes the direction of movement of the pivot point (left, right, up, down).  It doesn't rotate the rectangle.  You have a two dimensional object so you can only move it in two dimensions. If you have a coordinate axis and drew a vector from the center it would have a formula like y = ax + b if it was a straight line.  The line has an angle a.  It doesn't have a rotation. Now if it was a curve the formula would be y = ax^2 + bx + c.  You are trying to move your pivot point on both a straight line and a curve in 2-D at the same time which is impossible.